# When I use a method in division why does it count as a method and not as the returned values type(in this case an integer)?

Tags: python

I have a homework assignment to make a Time class. We have to overload the addition operator, and while setting it up, I am using the classes "total_minutes" method which returns the total number of minutes in the time. I am trying to divide it by 60 to get the hours (and %60 for minutes), but I get an error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'method' and 'int'" The way I am typing it is this:

```
total = self.total_minutes
new_hr = total/60
```

I don't understand why total is a method. If self.total_minutes returns an integer, then shouldn't total be the value that is returned by self.total_minutes (an integer)? I'll post the whole code, maybe there is something else I am missing, but I think that's the area where I need to type something differently because the total_minutes method works on its own.

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self, init_hr = 12, init_min = 0, init_ampm = "AM"):
        if init_hr < 1 or init_hr > 12:
            raise Exception("Error: Invalid hour for Time object")
        if init_min < 0 or init_min > 59:
            raise Exception("Error: Invalid minute for Time object")
        init_ampm = init_ampm.upper()
        if init_ampm != "AM" and init_ampm != "PM":
            raise Exception("Error: Invalid am/pm flag for Time object")

        self.hr = init_hr
        self.min = init_min
        self.ampm = init_ampm

    # IMPLEMENT THE REMAINING METHODS OF THE Time CLASS BELOW!!
    def hour(self):
        return self.hr
    def minute(self):
        return self.min
    def am_pm(self):
        return self.ampm
    def total_minutes(self):
        if self.ampm == "AM" and self.hr <= 11:
            return (self.hr*60 + self.min)
        elif self.ampm == "AM" and self.hr == 12:
            return self.min
        elif self.ampm == "PM" and self.hr <= 11:
            return (self.hr*60 + self.min + 720)
        else:
            return (int(self.hr*60 + self.min))
    def __str__(self):
        return ("%d:%02d%s"%(self.hr, self.min, self.ampm))
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
    def __add__(self, mins):
        total = self.total_minutes
        new_hr = total/60
        if new_hr > 12:
            new_ampm = "PM"
            new_hr == new_hr - 12
        else:
            new_ampm = "AM"
        new_min = total%60

        return Time(new_hr, new_min, new_ampm)
```

Comment: If you want to *call* `total_minutes`, you need to do `total_minutes()`.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are setting total EQUAL to the method here and not actually calling the method. To call the method do `self.total_minutes()`

Answer (score 2):

`total_minutes` is a method because that's how you defined it.  In order to run a method and get its return value, you must invoke it:

```
total = self.total_minutes()
```

The parentheses cause it to be invoked, giving the return value, which is presumably an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `total = self.total_minutes()` rather than what you currently have. What you currently have looks for a variable or a method within the `this` object. If you call `self.total_minutes()`, it executes the `total_minutes()` function and assigns that return value to the `total` variable. Without the parenthesis, it is setting total equal to the method itself, not what the method returns.  Whenever you call a function, you must use parenthesis even if you are not passing any parameters in the parenthesis.